# Convert url in address bar to localhost in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i need to create a marker in my web browser, to be faster in my job.
I need to convert some url like: https://www.myTest.com/section/the-new-section/ to
localhost/pf/section/the-new-section/
Maybe then i will need to add something after the address like ?_website=mypageSite, or something. but is secondary.
The thing is the first part.

I try to use this code like model to make main, but i can not achieve any result:

```
javascript:u=u=window.location.href.replace(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+/,%20%27%27).replace(/(\?|#).*$/,%20'');d=window.location.href.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?]+)/)[1];a='https://'+d+'/pf/api/v3/content/fetch/content-api-v4?query={%22website_url%22:%22'+u+'%22}';x=new%20XMLHttpRequest();x.open('GET',a,false);x.send(null);o=JSON.parse(x.responseText);if(o%20&&%20o._id){window.location.href%20=%20'https://diarioas.arcpublishing.com/composer/edit/'+o._id+'/';}else{'Story%20URL%20not%20found';}
```

i need similar to do that i comment before.
Some help for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

```js
const str = 'https://www.mytest.com/section/the-new-section/';

const url = new URL(str);

console.log(`localhost/pf${url.pathname}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases for this question,
First is when you are at that page`https://www.mytest.com/section/the-new-section/` then you then you can just use `window.location.pathname` to get the parameters and to get stuff like `?search=stackoverflow` you can use `window.location.search`

```js
console.log( "http://localhost"+window.location.pathname+window.location.search)
```

Second Interpretation is that you need a custom function to do this for a set of url's you provide... This is also similar to the above approach.

```js
var url = "https://www.mytest.com/section/the-new-section/?search=stackoverflow"
var urlt = new URL(url)
console.log("http://localhost" + urlt.pathname + urlt.search)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, all of them works fine in jsbin and local, but when i try to create my new javascript marker in chrome, not works. i have this now.
If i use this: javascript:alert(`localhost/pf${new URL(window.location.href).pathname}`);, works pefect!!!
But, when i change alert for window.open, or window.location.href.replace, not works.